# Run a function from while read line

Tags: bash, function, loops, ffmpeg, while-loop

I'm trying to run a function from while read line, the function contains ffmpeg commands to marge two files. but for some reason it's running the first `$line` and than breaks from loop.

"$filesList" contains three lines. I'm not sure what's wrong, but i can confirm with echo "$OFILE" that opener function runs three times  if I `comment out` the ffmpeg commands, and only once `with` ffmpeg commands.

```
opener(){
        OFILE="$1"
        echo "$OFILE"

        ffmpeg -i $opener_path -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts
        ffmpeg -i $OFILE -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2.ts
        ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc merge_$OFILE

        mv merge_$OFILE $OFILE
        rm intermediate1.ts intermediate2.ts
}


while read line; do
        if [ -e "$line" ]; then
                opener "$line"
        fi
done <<< "$filesList"
```

Comment: Try `set -e` and/or `set -v` to see what's really going on.

Comment: @rici shows noting special. as soon as it finishes the first loop the script ends without any additional command.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @chepner. Did you look really closely at how the ffmpeg command lines are parameter-expanded? (You could check  @chepner's theory by changing `opener "$line"` to `opener "$line"  </dev/null`)

Comment: @rici interesting, now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears one of the `ffmpeg` commands is reading from standard input, which consumes the rest of the contents of `$filesList` before the next call to `read`. <strike>I'm not familiar with `ffmpeg`, but two possibilities:</strike>

1. Does `-i` require an argument? Your posted code doesn't set the value of `opener_path`, so its unquoted expansion would produce an empty string that is discarded by the shell.
2. How is `concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts` interpreted by `ffmpeg`? Given the call to `rm`, it seems to produce a pair of files from an unknown source.

Comment: `$opener_path` is not empty 100% and the first file comes out merged. well I don't know how concat interpreted by ffmpeg... all i now it merges intermediate1.ts and intermediate2.ts. What do you meant by `seems to produce a pair of files from an unknown source`? I run rm on intermediate files I created previously by ffmpeg

Comment: Sorry, didn't scroll over far enough to see that they are produced by the first two calls to `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Explained here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089